# GCP Serverless VPC connector CPU usage more than 100%

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

In the Google monitoring console, I can see the Serverless VPC connector crosses the CPU utilization threshold (90%), above that it also crosses 100% and goes to 109%. Can someone help me understand, what will be the impact of such occurrences as I do not see any errors in application logs during that time. Or maybe I am looking it the wrong way?

[image: CPU Utilization]

**CPU Utilization**

[image]

**Number of bytes transferred delta**

Comment: Add the chart for network bandwidth that matches the CPU usage.

Comment: Added graph of n/w bandwidth

Comment: If the two images match each other for time, that defeats my idea that it was bandwidth usage. What are the min-instances and max-instances configuration settings? Since a VPC connector is a managed service, the service will autoscale out (but not back in). I am not sure what will happen if max-instances prevents autoscaling. A short-term spike of 109% will probably cause nothing to happen.